# div alignment off in safari & ios chrome

Tags: html, css, safari

I have been reprogramming my site to be responsive and been trying to figure this thing out for over a week, so thank you in advance.

I have what are essentially four 'blocks' on the main page, showing as a 2x2 grid on tablet/desktop screens. When shrunk to a mobile layout they become a vertical 1x4 grid. Simple enough and everything seems to work on all small, mobile screens. Everything looks fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE on desktop & Android.

On any version of Safari with an iPad screen or larger, the 2x2 grid is not aligned. Specifically, the bottom right block with the img in place of the title is about 10 pixels shifted down. Interestingly, Chrome on iPad also does this. I've read Chrome on iOS uses the Safari engine, so that may indicate this is a Safari-engine-specific issue.

I am almost certain the issue has to do with the title-spacing within the four divs, but I just can't figure this thing out even though it seems like it should be easy.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.sitecontainer {
  margin: none;
  width: 100%;
}

div.blocks {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Lusitana', serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 89%;
  text-align: center;
}

div.indexBlock {
  position: relative;
  height: 170px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Lusitana', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.indexBlock a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

div.blockTitle {
  font-family: 'Lusitana', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #1a66ff;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="siteContainer">

    <div class="blocks">

      <div class="indexBlock">
        <a href="https://google.com">
          <div class="blockTitle"><b>Title Title Title Title Title </b></div>
          Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="indexBlock">
        <a href="https://google.com">
          <div class="blockTitle"><b>Title Title Title Title Title </b></div>
          Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="indexBlock">
        <a href="https://google.com">
          <div class="blockTitle"><b>Title Title Title Title Title </b></div>
          Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="indexBlock">
        <a target="blank" href="http://www.google.com/">
          <img src="" alt="this block has an image in place of its title">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be related to the calculated baseline, and [the last mention in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html) that I've seen explicitly "does not define the position of the line box's baseline."

So Safari seems to calculate the position of the baseline differently. You can test this by changing the `vertical-position` on your image to another value, like `top` or `bottom`, and that will appear to clear things up.

Essentially what seems to be happening is that the img (`display: inline`) and the parent container (`display: inline-block`) are interacting badly based on the baseline calculation. The best way around it is likely to change the image to `display: block`, which is a common fix for alignment issues.

Comment: Your solution/s worked for this problem, so thanks for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately, when I implemented the changes on my full layout, it did not solve the problem, so there must be something else going on. I *really* thought I had narrowed it down.

Comment: followup - this was the problem, but it was actually the problem on the other divs, not the image one. Appreciate the help.